# How to get li to stretch down

Tags: html, css

the example can be seen here: http://www.animavivo.com

See the side where it says "Please a lot"/"Fault a man"/etc etc? I would like each li come straight down, preferably using percentages so that they can adapt based on how tall the title is. I have a feeling its an overflow problem but I don't know how to fix it without breaking anything else

I hope that makes sense. It's late and I'm not thinking straight. Thanks

Comment: Why are you nesting a `div` inside an `li`? Too much nesting has prevented the semantic overflow.

Comment: The li was added later and I haven't cleaned it up yet. Do you think applying the "secondary-post" class to the li will fix it? Edit: I cleaned up my code

Comment: I suggest removing the divs will fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed. What do I need to add to my code to make the li's stretch downwards?

Comment: Something like this? http://s21.postimg.org/6ezcnqtcn/screenshot_32.jpg

Comment: I am assuming that you will have only 4 titles in right side and fixed height container ? Am i right ?

Comment: You have a div `<div class="first-post" id="post-1">`, similarly add another div of the same relevance and insert your `ul` inside it and apply an `overflow:auto` property to that new inserted div. I hope your issue will be solved then. - @Tara

Comment: If you mean you want the total ul to be 100% high (as high as its parent, `div#magazine`), you will need to give the parent an explicit height (not in percentages) and  then you can give each `li` a height of 25%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

**The CSS Changes:**

```
#magazine {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #191919;
    height: 503px;
    overflow: auto;
}


#magazine ul {
    border-left: 8px solid #464646;
    height: 25%;
}
```

Change the CSS for the above and you will get your `li` to be stretched.

*PS: It works on resolution change also.*

Comment: That's what did it! Thank you so much, Nathan! Also thanks to everyone else who helped in the comments.

Comment: Not sure if it matters to you, but I'm getting a scrollbar on #magazine. It looks like your ul is extending past #magazine and making it scroll. Maybe put a max-height: 100% on the ul, or try 24.5% on each of the li's or just a little less than 25%.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give `#magazine` a fixed height lets say in your case 425px; and then you need to give `#magazine ul height:100%` and li to 25%.

CSS

```
#magazine {
    height: 425px;
}

#magazine ul {
    border-left: 8px solid #464646;
    background-color: #efefef;
    height: 100%;

}

#magazine ul li {
height: 25%
}
```

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264935/how-to-get-li-to-stretch-down/19265224#19265224)

Comment: @NathanLee yup you got a better solution for responsive too. +1 for your answer bro.

Comment: Thx vikas. +1 for your efforts too to help the OP get to the solution.